# Applying Spacy Parser to Pandas DataFrame w/ Multiprocessing

Tags: python, nlp, multiprocessing, spacy

Say I have a dataset, like

```
iris = pd.DataFrame(sns.load_dataset('iris'))
```

I can use `Spacy` and `.apply` to parse a string column into tokens (my real dataset has >1 word/token per entry of course)

```
import spacy # (I have version 1.8.2)
nlp = spacy.load('en')
iris['species_parsed'] = iris['species'].apply(nlp)
```

result:

```
   sepal_length   ... species    species_parsed
0           1.4   ... setosa          (setosa)
1           1.4   ... setosa          (setosa)
2           1.3   ... setosa          (setosa)
```

I can also use this convenient multiprocessing function ([thanks to this blogpost](http://www.racketracer.com/2016/07/06/pandas-in-parallel/)) to do most arbitrary apply functions on a dataframe in parallel:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, num_partitions):

    df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(num_partitions)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df
```

for example:

```
def my_func(df):
    df['length_of_word'] = df['species'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
    return df

num_cores = cpu_count()
iris = parallelize_dataframe(iris, my_func, num_cores)
```

result:

```
   sepal_length species  length_of_word
0           5.1  setosa               6
1           4.9  setosa               6
2           4.7  setosa               6
```

...But for some reason, I can't apply the Spacy parser to a dataframe using multiprocessing this way.

```
def add_parsed(df):
    df['species_parsed'] = df['species'].apply(nlp)
    return df

iris = parallelize_dataframe(iris, add_parsed, num_cores)
```

result:

```
   sepal_length species  length_of_word species_parsed
0           5.1  setosa               6             ()
1           4.9  setosa               6             ()
2           4.7  setosa               6             ()
```

Is there some other way to do this? I'm loving Spacy for NLP but I have a lot of text data and so I'd like to parallelize some processing functions, but ran into this issue.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Spacy is highly optimised and does the multiprocessing for you. As a result, I think your best bet is to take the data out of the Dataframe and pass it to the Spacy pipeline as a list rather than trying to use `.apply` directly.

You then need to the collate the results of the parse, and put this back into the Dataframe.

So, in your example, you could use something like:

```
tokens = []
lemma = []
pos = []

for doc in nlp.pipe(df['species'].astype('unicode').values, batch_size=50,
                        n_threads=3):
    if doc.is_parsed:
        tokens.append([n.text for n in doc])
        lemma.append([n.lemma_ for n in doc])
        pos.append([n.pos_ for n in doc])
    else:
        # We want to make sure that the lists of parsed results have the
        # same number of entries of the original Dataframe, so add some blanks in case the parse fails
        tokens.append(None)
        lemma.append(None)
        pos.append(None)

df['species_tokens'] = tokens
df['species_lemma'] = lemma
df['species_pos'] = pos
```

This approach will work fine on small datasets, but it eats up your memory, so not great if you want to process huge amounts of text.

Comment: so what is the recommended approach for big dataframes?

Comment: If you have a sequential index, I would enumerate the pipe and add the values inplace using `loc`

Comment: To avoid using up the cache memory, you could write to a file on disk one line at a time. In later stages of your analysis, you may use those newly created artifacts.

Comment: The `n_threads` parameter of `pipe()` was [deprecated in 2019](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2075#issuecomment-465966796).  `n_process` would be a reasonable substitute.

Comment: The `doc.is_parsed` attribute is [deprecated](https://spacy.io/usage/v3#section-incompat) as of spacy v3.0. The documentation suggests using `doc.has_annotation("DEP")` instead.